# Using Windows Credentials Manager from Windows Docker Container

Tags: windows, docker, containers

Q: Is it possible to connect to the host server's Windows Vault Credential Manager to access username and password information for your .NET dll.

I'm very unfamiliar with the windows vault for credentials, but do know that containers are not supposed to see anything on the host unless explicitly told they've got access. So, how, (if at all possible) would you start a docker container (windows) on a Windows Server 2016 or 2019 instance to access the vault?

The problem here is that the source code for the .NET dll used in this case cannot be re-written to find its credentials in another way - it always uses the vault. I want to know if it is at all possible to use such a dll inside a windows container. In this case the container can be servercore, not nanoserver, if that somehow helps the matter.

Here's an example for how a .NET application can use the credentials of the vault:
https://vimalshekar.github.io/scriptsamples/Getting-Stored-Web-Credentials-using-PowerShell

I've been unable to find any material on the subject - it seems the vault simply is not used for containers at all, which makes me believe that what I'm looking for is not possible. I would still like to know the details on this:

1: Is it possible?
2: Why / Why not?
3: If it is possible: How to achieve it for your container, with an example.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm looking to do something similar

Comment: Unfortunately we never found a solution for this and we ended up not using the particular .dll at all in the project.